# Polymer core-iconset-svg missing parts

Tags: svg, polymer

For any `<g>` tag in `<svg><defs>` for a **core-iconset-svg**. If the `<g>` has more than one child like `<circle>, <path>, <rect>` etc. The polymer app will only render the first child element. This is true even for the core-icons. Here is an example of two icons from the core-icons. The **drive-ms-excel** renders fine because it has only one path but the **drive-ms-powerpoint** only renders the first path but not the second which contains the center of the **P**.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is not working properly. Has anyone else run accross this.

```
<g id="drive-ms-excel">
    <path d="M19,3H5C3.9,3,3,3.9,3,5v14c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h14c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V5C21,3.9,20.1,3,19,3z M16.2,17h-2L12,13.2L9.8,17h-2l3.2-5L7.8,7h2l2.2,3.8L14.2,7h2L13,12L16.2,17z"/>
</g>
<g id="drive-ms-powerpoint">
    <path d="M19,3H5C3.9,3,3,3.9,3,5v14c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h14c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V5C21,3.9,20.1,3,19,3z M9.8,13.4V17H8V7h4.3c1.5,0,2.2,0.3,2.8,0.9c0.7,0.6,0.9,1.4,0.9,2.3c0,1-0.3,1.8-0.9,2.3c-0.6,0.5-1.3,0.8-2.8,0.8H9.8z"/>
    <path d="M9.8,12V8.4h2.3c0.7,0,1.2,0.2,1.5,0.6c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.5,1.2c0,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5,1.3c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-1.4,0.5H9.8z"/>
</g>
```

http://appmite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/missing-part.png